# LAMP : как установить оффлайн?

Tags: lamp, linux

Подскажите плиз,  не могу я всякий раз, когда надо установить LAMP скачивать одно и тоже с сети. Хотелось бы один раз скачать пакет LAMP и добавить в свою локальную репозиторию и отсюда установить уже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что вы используете систему, родственную Debian (Ubuntu, Mint и т.п.), тогда для установки пакетов оффлайн есть удобное средство - [Keryx](http://keryxproject.org/). Сначала вы загрузите нужные пакеты с зависимостями для LAMP (это apache2 и mysql-server) на флэшку, затем сможете установить их командой

```
dpkg -i <файл>
```